# How to do performance testing with key-cloak authentication in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, keycloak

I try to do performance testing but particular site have enable key-cloak authentication.any suggesstions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), the exact steps will be different for [OpenID Connect](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/openid-connect-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter/) and [SAML](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites) so you need to determine which [client protocol](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#assembly-managing-clients_server_administration_guide) is being used in that particular Keycloak instance.

In order to get help with correlating individual parameters you will need to provide the previous response and the format of the next request so we could come up with the relevant instructions for JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) setup.

Comment: can you demonstrate how to do those steps